# How to assign varnames() and longnames() to SpatRaster before writting it to a NetCDF file?

Tags: r, terra

I'm trying to save Geo2D data obtained from HDF5 to a NetCDF file using `terra` package in `R`. However, I'm not able to change the variable name, both short and long names, as you can in the data information as well as in the image attached.

Reproducible example:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(xmin=-180, xmax=180,ymin=-90, ymax=90, nrows=18, ncols=36)

values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

# assign time
terra::time(r)<-as.POSIXct(959818500,origin = "1970-01-01",tz = "UTC")

#assign units
terra::units(r)<-"mm hr -1"

#assign short name 
terra::varnames(r)<-"pr"

#assign long name 
terra::longnames(r)<-"Precipitation"

writeCDF(x = r,
                filename = "reproducible_example.nc",
                compression = 9,
                missval=1e32,
                overwrite=TRUE)
```

SpatRaster Information:

```
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 18, 36, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : memory 
varname     : reproducible_example 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     1 
max value   :   648 
time        : 2000-06-01 00:15:00
```

Image from [Panoply](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/):
[image]

**EDIT:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] terra_1.4-15        lubridate_1.8.0     rgdal_1.5-27        hdf5r_1.3.4         stringr_1.4.0      
 [6] abind_1.4-5         raster_3.5-2        sp_1.4-5            gdalUtils_2.0.3.2   ncdf4.helpers_0.3-6
[11] ncdf4_1.17          DescTools_0.99.43   ffbase_0.13.3       ff_4.0.4            bit_4.0.4          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        compiler_4.1.1    R.methodsS3_1.8.1 R.utils_2.11.0    class_7.3-19      iterators_1.0.13 
 [7] tools_4.1.1       boot_1.3-28       rootSolve_1.8.2.3 lattice_0.20-44   Matrix_1.3-4      foreach_1.5.1    
[13] fastmatch_1.1-3   rstudioapi_0.13   parallel_4.1.1    mvtnorm_1.1-3     expm_0.999-6      e1071_1.7-9      
[19] generics_0.1.1    bit64_4.0.5       gld_2.6.2         grid_4.1.1        data.table_1.14.2 R6_2.5.1         
[25] lmom_2.8          magrittr_2.0.1    codetools_0.2-18  MASS_7.3-54       Exact_3.0         proxy_0.4-26     
[31] stringi_1.7.5     R.oo_1.24.0
```

Comment: Hello @ahmathelte. Don't know what the problem is. When I run your code, the `varname` information of the SpatRaster is updated correctly. So the problem does not seem to be in your code.

Comment: Hello @lovalery! I added the my Session info to the question :)

Comment: Hello @ahmathelte. Two possible hypotheses:  (i) I use R 4.0.2. So, there may be a problem with the last version of R... Maybe try with an earlier version; (ii) I am not running the latest version of `terra` (i.e. 1.3.22). Actually, I don't think the problem comes from there but it can't be excluded a priori...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(xmin=-180, xmax=180,ymin=-90, ymax=90, nrows=18, ncols=36)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
time(r) <- as.POSIXct(959818500,origin = "1970-01-01",tz = "UTC")

x <- writeCDF(r, "test.nc", "pr", longname="Precipitation", unit="mm hr -1", overwrite=TRUE)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 18, 36, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : test.nc 
#varname     : pr (Precipitation) 
#name        :       pr 
#unit        : mm hr -1 
#time        : 2000-06-01 00:15:00
```

Or

```
s <- sds(r)
units(s) <- "mm hr -1"
varnames(s) <- "pr"
longnames(s) <- "Precipitation"
y <- writeCDF(s, "test2.nc", overwrite=TRUE)
y
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 18, 36, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : test2.nc 
#varname     : pr (Precipitation) 
#name        :       pr 
#unit        : mm hr -1 
#time        : 2000-06-01 00:15:00
```

The `sds` route allows you to write multiple variables to one file.

See `?terra::writeCDF`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the great package :). The second solution works, I have tried the earlier before/after posting the question and it didn't work, just FYI :)

Comment: and after your answer!*

Comment: second approach worked for me; the first approach variables like varname, longname, etc, did not write to file